# Как проверить возрастание цифр в числе?

Tags: python, численные-методы

Все числа из последовательности, которые составлены из цифр, идущих
по возрастанию необходимо перевернуть и вывести на экран.
Пример. Вход: 4 87 129 33 45 Выход: 921 54.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант.

```
def increases(number):
    flag = True
    for i in range(1, len(number)):
        if not number[i] > number[i-1]:
            flag = False
            break
    return flag and len(number) >= 2
    
lst = input().split()
new_lst = []
for num in lst:
    if increases(num):
        new_lst.append(num[::-1])
print(*new_lst)
```

Comment: редактирую сообщение, т.к. вы изменили условие

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(z => int.Parse(z.Reverse().ToArray())).OrderBy(x => x).Reverse()));
```

Ввод: `19 417 1293 19 72 31 719 312 93 71 19` 
Вывод: `3921 917 714 213 91 91 91 39 27 17 13`

Comment: Вопрос по python.

Comment: @magistar, Во время отправки вопроса в метках было: [python] [C#] [C++]

Comment: понял. там и условие сначала другое было)

Comment: Да вроде так же как и было

Comment: Вы наверное позже зашли). Там сначала просто было, как проверить то, что число с цифрами по возрастанию. А потом полное условие задачи добавилось)

Answer (score -1):

```
value = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

numbers = list(value)

start = numbers[0]

my_list = []

for i in numbers:
    if i >= start:
        my_list.append(i)
        start = i

sorted(my_list, reverse=True) if numbers == my_list else 'Номера не упорядочены' # [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

value = 1, 2, 3, 2   # 'Номера не упорядочены'
```

Comment: Отредактировано по условию

Comment: Вообще непонятно что здесь происходит.